# How do I get a Access Token for my Microsoft Personal Account - Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am working on a project, that sorts my emails in to folders in Python. I having a @outlook.com email and I am going to be using Microsoft Graph API. First I have just been using cURL to try out the different endpoints.

I have had a few problems, I am trying to get my personal access token, so I can use the endpoint `/me/messages` I have tried many different ways to authenticate using the documentation, but none of them seem to work. I don't have any active directory, I just want to use my own personal account, which I have selected when creating the project. Since my project is going to be running on the backend, I will be using the Application permissions instead of Delegated permission (please tell me if it is possible to use application permissions with my idea)

It would be helpful, if people could send me the cURL commands, to get my access token and maybe a example request to get my emails. Then I can translate this into Python code. If I receive any errors while executing your commands I will just comment on your answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the following documents I do not believe it is possible to use application permissions for a non-interactive (daemon) solution with a Microsoft Account.  Only delegated permissions are supported since you as a user will not be able to grant admin consent on your Microsoft Account.

"Daemon applications can be used only with Azure AD organizations. It doesn't make sense to try to use daemon applications to manipulate Microsoft personal accounts. The admin consent will never be granted."

[Scenario: Daemon application that calls web APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-overview#specifics)

[Account type support in authentication flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-supported-account-types#account-type-support-in-authentication-flows)

Comment: Can you please tell me what permission I would need to use and some commands to execute to get my access token, or would I have to use a library or something to get the Oauth consent screen.

Comment: @Jpac14 please see the documentation on this page for [Authorization and sign-in for OneDrive in Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/graph-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online).  It also covers permissions (scopes) needed under the "Authentication scopes" section.

In terms of libraries take a look at Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) which is available for a number of [languages and frameworks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-overview#languages-and-frameworks)